# Cloned ee2 site not working due to "undefined variable: templateGroup"

Tags: templates

This is an EE2 site that I have cloned from production. I've copied all files and cloned the backing database. I'm able to enter the control panel and most things appear to be working.

However, when I attempt to load a page that relies on templates I get the "undefined variable: templateGroup".

These files exists in the same path and show up in the Template Manager. I've not been able to find anything in the configuration that I can change to fix this.

The only other reference I found to this bug, is when upgrading EE2, but I'm not upgrading -- just cloning the site.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried disabling extensions to see if there is an issue with an extension that's causing this? `$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';`
https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#allow-extensions

Comment: Have you tried to synchronize the templates? https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/cp/design/templates/synchronize_templates.html